# generating licenses.licx

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, licensing, licenses.licx, emptylicenseslicx

I've got a bit of a problem. I'm moving my source repository from one machine to another, and in the process I'm doing some culling of what's stored as I've learned more about creating/managing a repository since I started.

The problem is that we're using dxperience tools from devexpress and it uses the .net license system (licenses.licx). Originally I had this license in the repository, and [I'm hearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363/how-does-the-licenses-licx-based-net-component-licensing-model-work) that this isn't necessarily the best idea. So I haven't included it in the repository. But now, when I checkout the project from the repository on my machine (same machine that I was checking out to before the move), it's looking for the license file and not generating it as (I think) it should be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have run into the same problem using Infragistics controls.

Our solution has been to keep a blank licnenses.licx file in our source repository (Source Gear Vault) and then change the properties of the file to Read Only false on our local workations.  This way we do not end up stepping on each other with that file and it is generated with the proper keys off of our workstations.

Of course this is a bit of a manual work around that may not be suitable for you, but that is how we have been doing it.

Comment: I just tried deleting the licenses.licx from the resources section in my ide for each project that needed one, and then rebuilt the solution with success. But if I remove it from the solution and then commit that to the repository, each checking will want to commit the changes to the csproj

Comment: recreating the problem all over again. Fortunately, right now we're a small team (2) so I can just note to the other developer that removing the file from the solution and rebuilding will work, but I'll have to find another solution when the time comes.

Comment: That's what I've been doing as well for years. Eventually got tired of doing it manually, and automated it via a NuGet package - https://github.com/caioproiete/EmptyLicensesLicx

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can install the [EmptyLicensesLicx](https://github.com/caioproiete/EmptyLicensesLicx) nuget package, and it will make sure there's an empty `Licenses.licx` in your project, before it gets compiled (which is all you need).

Answer (score 1):

This file should be compiled into your deployment assemblies automatically by having licenses.licx included as an **embedded resource**.  Under the hood, Visual studio uses lc.exe to include this in your assemblies.

http://www.atalasoft.com/kb/Article.aspx?id=10103

Answer (score -1):

1. delete existing licence file
2. solve all errors
3. check properties of solution, DLL name, source name
4. rebuild the project