# VS2019 CS1566 when project has an licx file init

Tags: c#, telerik, visual-studio-2019, licenses.licx

Recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2019. If there is a licenses.licx license file present in the project properties folder, the following error occurs at build time:

> error CS1566: Error reading resource 'MyProgram.exe.licenses' --
>   'Could not find file
>   'C:\Sourcecodefolder\obj\x64\Debug\MyProgram.exe.licenses'.'

I tried setting "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always", on the .licx file. but that didn't help.

If I delete the license file, the app builds OK. As soon as I open a Windows form, Telerik create a new .licx file and adds it to the project. So every time I open a form in designer view, I have to go delete the .licx file before it will build. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't have VS2019 but maybe it helps to create an empty license file and set it to read-only?

Comment: Also consider this solution, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067795/how-can-i-prevent-visual-studio-from-creating-license-licx/18070844#18070844

Comment: After it creates a license file, I set it to "No Action" for its build action. Works until I pull from source control and overwrite the project.

Answer (score 0):

I automate that by installing [EmptyLicensesLicx](https://github.com/caioproiete/EmptyLicensesLicx) NuGet package, which will make sure there's always an empty `Licenses.licx` file in your project, before it gets compiled (which is all you really need).