# licenses.licx missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, licenses.licx, emptylicenseslicx, licenseslicx

I have recently recovered my lost files and in my C# project, it seems "licenses.licx" file has been gone.

This is the VS error:

> "Could not find file 'C:...\Exam\Properties\licenses.licx'"

How can I fix this error and regenerate "licenses.licx" file?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363/how-does-the-licenses-licx-based-net-component-licensing-model-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create another project and copy your existing code to it.

Answer (score 11):

Just exclude any licenses.licx from your project.
To exclude a file, find the file in solution explorer and right-click on it, choose "Exclude From Project". done.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the cause of problem is that the licenses.licx file is included in the project. So, I suggest that you exclude it from the application to avoid this problem. Right-click on this file in the project tree and select the 'Exclude From Project' menu item.
Thanks,

Comment: Thanks dear Hossein. This question asked long time ago but thanks for sharing knowledge dude!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can install the [EmptyLicensesLicx](https://github.com/caioproiete/EmptyLicensesLicx) nuget package, and it will make sure there's an empty `Licenses.licx` in your project, before it gets compiled.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to properties folder of that project
2. create  new text file.
3. rename it to  licenses.licx
4. hit f5